# Undo a function that is not (seemingly) hooked to an action?

Tags: functions, comments, include, comments-template

I am using the popular Disqus plugin. To use this plugin effectively, they [advise](http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/565624-tightening-your-disqus-integration) you to change the URL on the front page to end in `#disqus_thread`. I know how to easily do this in jQuery, but I figured it would be easier if I could just edit a template.

I found the link is generated in `get_comments_link()` , which can be found in `wp-includes\comment-template.php`.

```
function get_comments_link($post_id = 0) {
    return apply_filters( 'get_comments_link', get_permalink( $post_id ) . '#comments', $post_id );
}
```

But how would I go about changing something in an wp-include file? Can I put the edits in my functions.php? And if so, how? I know how to "undo" functions, **but how do you do that when they are not (seemingly) hooked to an action**?

Comment: The article you linked to seems to be for custom-developed websites, and not necessarily related to the WordPress plugin implementation.  If changing the comment link is necessary, wouldn't the [Disqus WordPress plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/disqus-comment-system/) (which is written by Disqus) handle this automatically?

Comment: Please close this as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18783534/undo-a-function-in-wordpress-that-is-not-seemingly-hooked-to-an-action/18783823?noredirect=1#18783823

Comment: possible duplicate of [Override parent theme function that is not hooked or in the functions.php file](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/101238/override-parent-theme-function-that-is-not-hooked-or-in-the-functions-php-file)

Answer (score 0):

If you are 100% sure that is the line you have to change then just create your own function to do the same thing.

```
function my_popup_link() {
    echo get_permalink() . '#disqus_thread';
}
```

Then replace the function call in your template with your own.

Comment: I would like to keep the other functionality that is present in the function (password-protected etc.).

Comment: @BramVanroy Then copy the whole function, change the line you want, and re-implement it in your functions file.

Comment: `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare comments_popup_link() (previously declared in C:\xampp\htdocs\mobielinformatie\wp-includes\comment-template.php:968) in C:\xampp\htdocs\mobielinformatie\wp-content\themes\mobielinformatie\functions.php on line 123` So it's not as easy as that.

Comment: @BramVanroy you need to give your function another name!

Comment: Yes, but that won't undo the current function. I have to disable the original function as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just add another filter for the comments links:

```
function wpse_113586_add_disqus_hash($url) {
    return substr($url, 0, strpos($url, '#')).'#disqus_thread';
} // function wpse_113586_add_disqus_hash
add_filter('get_comments_link', 'wpse_113586_add_disqus_hash', 999)
```