# How can I find the hook I need to rewrite a function?

Tags: hooks

I want to change the behavior of a bbpress/Buddypress "create group" page. I found the function I need to rewrite, it's the function `create_screen` in plugins/bbpress/includes/extend/buddypress/group.php. I think I need to do something like

```
remove_action( 'some_hook_here', 'create_screen'  );  
add_action( 'some_hook_here', 'create_screen' );
```

But I don't know what hook I have to use, or where to find it. This is my first time trying to write a wordpress plugin, so I'm a little lost.

Comment: plugins/buddypress/readme.txt says it's version 1.8.1. I guess what I'm looking at is more of an extension to bbpress that interfaces with Buddypress.

Comment: Just to clarify, the file you are looking at is in the [bbPress](http://wordpress.org/plugins/bbpress/) plugin, not the [BuddyPress](http://wordpress.org/plugins/buddypress/) plugin.

Comment: See: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/103644/21376

Comment: @s_ha_dum, Thanks, that's helpful. I still can't find the relevant hook for the function I want to rewrite, though--there don't seem to be any `do_action()` around the function I'm trying to rewrite, and maybe that's not what I should be looking for.

Comment: There may not be a relevant hook. If there is no hook, or other mechanism that lets you override the function, then you can't override it. See this too: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/101240/21376

Comment: But if there is a relevant hook, how would I go about finding it?

Comment: To find hooks, search for `apply_filters` or `do_action` calls.

Answer (score 0):

BuddyPress defines a class named `BP_Group_Extension` which can be used by plugins or themes as an API for creating group extensions.  This base class is located in [`buddypress/bp-groups/bp-groups-classes.php`](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/buddypress/tags/1.8.1/bp-groups/bp-groups-classes.php), and there is documentation on how to use it in the file at the beginning of the class definition (starting at line 1742).

bbPress uses this BuddyPress API to modify the BuddyPress functionality.  In bbPress, the class where you found the `create_screen` function is named `BBP_Forums_Group_Extension` and it extends the `BP_Group_Extension` class.  If you want to create a plugin to modify this further, you can extend the class further and redefine the `create_screen` function.

Comment: Thanks, thanks makes a lot of sense. But when I write a `class MLA_BBP_Forums_Group_Extension extends BBP_Forums_Group_Extension { function create_screen() {` in my plugin file, it doesn't seem to affect anything.